# Tabledit Jquery doesnt work if datatable fetched with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/. It works perfectly when I have the datatable with PHP.

However when I do the same with AJAX, the datatable is not recognized (functionalities doesn't work)

I was wondering if it could be any workaround to get this work or is it in general when you fetch you cant use it with javascript after its fetched?

I am also open for any suggestion for a live editable datatable library

Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  fetch_orderdetails()

  function fetch_orderdetails() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/v1/orders/1",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(orderdetails) {
        var html = '';
        for (var count = 0; count < orderdetails.length; count++) {
          alert(orderdetails[count].coincode);
          html += '<tr style="text-align:center!important;">';
          html += '<td style="display:none;">' + orderdetails[count].id + '</td>';
          html += '<td>' + orderdetails[count].jeton + '</td>';
          html += '<td>' + orderdetails[count].triggerpricebuy + '</td>';
          html += '<td>' + orderdetails[count].triggerpricesell + '</td>';
          html += '<td>' + orderdetails[count].availableusd + '</td>';
          html += '<td>Action</td>';
          html += '<td>' + orderdetails[count].coincode + '</td>';
          html += '</tr>';
        }
        $('tbody#orderdetails').html(html);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-12">
    <div class="table-responsive text-white table-hover fs-14" style="">
      @csrf
      <table id="editable" class="table table-striped  display mb-4 dataTablesCard short-one  card-table text-black" style="font-size:1.1rem; text-align:center!important; color:white!important;">
        <thead style="font-size:1.5rem!important;">
          <tr>
            <th style="display:none!important;">id</th>
            <th style="padding-left: 0px!important; padding-right:0px!important;">Jeton</th>
            <th>BuyPrice</th>
            <th>SellPrice</th>
            <th>$ Value</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>OrderType</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="orderdetails">
          // For non-Ajax version only difference I have a foreach loop here with the same source with same classes and other details.
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

PHP CODE added below it is used on the first HTML inside of the TBODY tags

```html
<tbody>
                @foreach($ordersetup as $orderlines)
                
                @if ($orderlines->status == 0)
                @php 
                
                $bgcolororderlines = 'background:##05031a;';
                $buttonicon = "play";
                $buttonurl = "activate";
                $buttonclass = "success";
                $jetonbackgroundcolor='background:#370e12;'; 
                @endphp
    
                @else
                @php 
                $bgcolororderlines = 'background:##0688ba;';
                $buttonicon = "pause";
                $buttonurl = "pause";
                $buttonclass = "warning";
                $jetonbackgroundcolor='background:#17370e;';
                
                
                @endphp
                @endif
                
                <tr style="{{$bgcolororderlines}} ">
    
                  @if ($orderlines->jeton==0)
                  @php $badgeclass='badge badge-danger'; @endphp
                  
                  @else 
                  @php $badgeclass='badge badge-warning'; @endphp
                  
                      
                  @endif
                  <td style="display:none!important;">{{ $orderlines->id }}</td>
                  <td style=""><div class="{{$badgeclass}}">{{ $orderlines->jeton }}</div></td>
                  <td>{{ $orderlines->triggerpricebuy }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $orderlines->triggerpricesell }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $orderlines->availableusd }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $orderlines->coincode }}</td>
                  <td></td>   
                  </tr>
              @endforeach
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Where is your php code? it is difficult to answer without watching your php code, we need to know how you are sending data from there, I suggest you to understand the output from php file, or just echo out the required html code with database data in php file itself and then append it to the source page after Ajax?

Comment: @MohammedKhurram I've added the PHP code as well Thank you!